# How to print a chromaticity diagram in LaTeX with labelled points on it?

Tags: diagrams

How do I print a chromaticity diagram (Ideally a [CIE 1931 plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIE_1931_color_space#CIE_xy_chromaticity_diagram_and_the_CIE_xyY_color_space)) with certain coordinates on it labelled.

Something like this (made with non-LaTeX software I don't have access to until after the Christmas break and would have to go into campus to use, which is strongly discouraged if not absolutely needed due to the pandemic).

[image: A CIE 1931 diagram with point labelled A and 1-5]

What I have found so far: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422862/fill-area-of-the-spectral-curve-with-cie-chromaticity-fading-to-generate-a-cie-c) lead me to the [`pst-cie`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-cie) package, which looks like a very easy way to draw the diagram, but its documentation doesn't explain how to label specific points. It has examples of adding a curve to it, but I need points rather then a curve, and its documentation is...very barebones to the point I'm not sure how to do anything but recreate the examples in the pdf.

There is also [this TikZ answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177079/tikz-chromaticity-diagram) but I don't know TikZ so I'd have no idea how to start adapting it to my needs. (I know a little bit of `pgfplots` which is why I was very hopeful about `pst-cie`, but it appears to use a totally different syntax style.

Also, none of the answers are in `pdflatex` which is what I'm currently using, though I guess if I had to I could move to `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.

Note: I will take "there is currently no easy or good way to do this in LaTeX" as a valid answer, I have a `GNUplot` script that can do the same thing if need be, it would just be nice to do everything inside LaTeX.

Comment: I've just been told that calling GNUplot from within TikZ is possible, which seems a way to do this!

Comment: Could you post the `pstricks` code you've tried?

Comment: @Bernard I haven't tried yet, I just looked over the examples and couldn't see how to start. Right now I'm trying using an existing GNUplot script written by a former grad student within TikZ and if I get it working I'll answer my own question.

Comment: What are the specific points you'd like to label? Is it A, 3,4,5 as shown in the posted image?

Comment: @Bernard I'm going to be specifying those based on data that I don't have yet, but those work for an initial test. The labels will be more like "Eu" "Tb" etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is just for fun but it appears that already the color wheel yields something that is not too dissimilar. This suggests that if you derive the contour instead of just approximating it by a parabola you might have something that can be used till you get to your lab to produce the "real thing".

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={alpha=270;s=3;
    a=0.8;b=0.5;c=1.6;R=max(sqrt(a*a+b*b),c);}]
 \begin{scope}  
  \clip[rotate=30] (-a*s,-b*s) parabola bend (0,c*s) (a*s,-b*s);
  \shade[shading=color wheel,transform canvas={rotate=alpha,xscale=-1}] 
    (0,0) circle[radius=R*s];
 \end{scope}    
 \draw[rotate=30] (-a*s,-b*s) parabola bend (0,c*s) (a*s,-b*s);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]